# exec a parameter that is a function javascript

Tags: javascript, function-parameter

I have an object that contains a lot of arrays inside. This array content function-paramenters.

for example: `object = {"elem" : [fn1, fn2], "other-elem" : [fn3, fn4, fn5], ... }`

I want to make a method who receive a name and when this name fixes with the object element key, it have to execute all the functions that are in this array.

How can I exec this functions?

Comment: "object" is a bad variable name...

Comment: the variable that I am using hasn't really this name... it was only an example to show what I had. but thanks for the advice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Exec function should be like this

```
function Exec(ElementName)
{
    if (object[ElementName])
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < object[ElementName].length; i++)
            object[ElementName][i]();
    }
}
Exec('elem');
```

Answer (score 2):

use this to get your functions

```
 object["elem"]
```

in jQuery you could use

```
$(object["elem"]).each(function(index,value){
   value();
});
```

in native JavaScript you could use

```
for(var i = 0; i < object["elem"].length; i++)
{
   object["elem"][i]();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just call it by using `()` :

```
var fnarray = object[name];
var i;
for (i = 0; i<fnarray.length; i++) {
  fnarray[i](); // execute the function
}
```